# Integral equation or what?

Tags: integration

Actually this is my own question.

Is there a way to solve:

$$\int_0^8x^r\,\mathbb{d}x=32$$

Even if, without compute the equation we already know from trial and error that the answer is $r=1$.

When i tried inputting that equation on wolfram alpha,

This is my input ->

> ∫[0,8]x^r dx=32

there are 2 answers: 2 real solutions (including about lambert W function form) and 1 real integer solution which is $1$.

Comment: can you please change the tag, I guess its misplaced.

Comment: Have you tried using Newton's method or any other root-approximation methods? BTW there are only two values of $r$ that satisfy the equation: the other scary-looking value on Wolfram Alpha actually equals $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $r=-1$ then the integral diverges, and if $r\neq-1$ we get
$$32=\int_0^8x^r\,{\rm d}x=\left[\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}\right]_0^8=\frac{8^{r+1}}{r+1}.$$
A bit of rearranging and setting $s:=-3\ln(2)(r+1)$ shows that this is equivalent to
$$se^s=-\frac{3\ln2}{32}.$$
By definition of the Lambert $W$ function(s) the solutions to this equation are precisely the values of
$$W_k\left(-\frac{3\ln2}{32}\right),$$
whenever this is defined, as $k$ ranges over the integers. Because the argument $-\tfrac{3\ln2}{32}$ is a negative real number (greater than $-e^{-1}$), these values are real numbers only for $k=0$ and $k=-1$. This yields the solutions
$$W_0\left(-\frac{3\ln2}{32}\right)\approx0.966495\ldots
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
W_{-1}\left(-\frac{3\ln2}{32}\right)=1.$$

Answer (score 1):

You can simply solve the integral: $\displaystyle{\int_a^b x^r dx}=\left[\dfrac{1}{r+1}x^{r+1}\right]_a^b$.

This results in $4(r+1)=8^r$. Now if you plot the function $r\longmapsto 8^r$, e.g. on WolframAlpha, then you will see that its graph crosses the line $r\longmapsto 4(r+1)$ twice.